# filling NaN value in a df based on the first value in month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a df as below (after concat) I want to fill the NaN value with the first value of the corresponding month (e.g. 05/05/74 to be filled with 5 and 01/06/74 to be filled with NaN)
is there a pythonic way manipulating pandas dataframes to achieve so?

| Date | values |
| --- | --- |
| 01/05/74 | 5 |
| 05/05/74 | NaN |
| 26/05/74 | 6 |
| 01/06/74 | Nan |
| 03/06/74 | NaN |

Comment: If there is a null value for 27/05/74, the replacement value should be 5 or 6?

Comment: @Corralien the question is clear about this: 5. I'm unsure whether OP is aware that the question is clear about this, though ...

Comment: Should be 5 yes during May

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your column `Date` to `datetime64` then group monthly and fill values:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y')

df['values'] = df['values'].combine_first(df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.to_period('M'))['values'].transform('first'))
print(df)

# Output
        Date values
0 1974-05-01      5
1 1974-05-05      5
2 1974-05-26      6
3 1974-06-01    Nan
4 1974-06-03    Nan
```